# Clojure: What happens when 'persistent!' is called on a TransientVector?

Tags: java, data-structures, clojure

I'm going through the source code of clojure compiler and have encountered behavior which doesn't seem to match the source code.

The `PersistentVector` class in `clojure.lang` (https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentVector.java), which is implemented as a bit partitioned trie has the following fields:

1. cnt (int)
2. tail (Object[])
3. root (Node)
4. shift (int)
5. _meta

`Node` has two fields. `edit` and `array`.

`array` stores the children(branches of the trie), and `edit` is an `AtomicReference<Thread>`. `edit` contains `null` for `PersistentVector`s and the id of thread of creation for `TransientVector`s. [This](http://www.hypirion.com/musings/understanding-clojure-transients) blog post explains very nicely how the transients actually work. The key point which relates to my query are:

1. Any new nodes created by the transient will have `edit` field set to that of the root of transient, which contains the id of creation thread
2. when `persistent!` is called on a `TransientVector`, the `edit` of the root node is set to null and a `PersistentVector` is created from this root, which is returned. This behavior can be seen [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/a1722cf9a15d917ee78a117732cf5c5e01fe3557/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentVector.java#L560) in the source code.

Note that the `edit` field of only the root node is set to null, so any new nodes, which were created by the transient, with the `edit` set to thread id, will remain unaffected. So I wrote the following code to test this case:

```
package clojure.lang;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<32; i++) {
            arr.add(i);
        }

        PersistentVector pv1 = PersistentVector.create((Iterable)arr);
        PersistentVector.TransientVector tv1 = pv1.asTransient();

        tv1.conj(-1);
        PersistentVector.Node n = (PersistentVector.Node) tv1.root.array[0];
        System.out.println(n.edit);

        PersistentVector pv2 = tv1.persistent();
        n = (PersistentVector.Node) pv2.root.array[0];
        System.out.println(n.edit);

        System.out.println("end");

    }
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
Thread[main,5,main]
null
end
```

That's what this code does:

1. Creates a `PersistentVector` with 32 elements. This vector will have a full tail, so adding any element to it will result in the creation of a new node
2. Created a `TransientVector` from it.
3. Adds an element to the transient. This will cause a new node to be created, which will be stored as a child of `root`.
4. prints the value of the `edit` field of this new node
5. makes the transient `persistent`
6. prints the `edit` field of the same node.

The value of that field gets reset to null! I can't figure out how that happens. I've tried setting field watchpoint in intellij but that breakpoint isn't triggered at all when `tv1.persistent()` is called. What's the reason behind this behaviour? I've tried it with vectors with more elements and the value of `edit` field gets reset for all the children nodes when the `persistent` is called on the `TransientVector`.